# How to add caret class into menu,which have sub-menu(s) in it only

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to add (or show, I don't really know should I need to add or show that class).

I want it to show on parent elements which has only sub menus.
I don't really know what should I put into my jQuery code. That's why I didn't paste anything here.

I'm working on wordpress. Here is picture of caret design:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vQeL.png]

Sorry for the small info guys, if you need any more info to help me, just ask.
Don't know what else should i put here.

```css
/************************************************
Mobile-Menu Design.
************************************************/

.mobile-menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
  top: 10.2%;
  color: black;
  position:relative;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mobile-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.mobile-menu > ul> li:hover > a, .mobile-menu > ul> li:hover > .sub-menu > li:hover > a, .mobile-menu > ul .sub-menu  .sub-menu > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

.mobile-menu ul li ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

/************************************************
Caret Design 
************************************************/

.caret {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;   
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.caret:before {
    content: "";
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -24px;
    left: 45%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.caret:after {
    content: "";
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 45%;
}

.caret.show {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
    <ul class="mobile-menu-ul">
        <div class="caret"></div>
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array (
            'theme_location'=> 'new-menu',
            'container' => '', 
            'items_wrap' => '%3$s' 
        )); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This worpress site?

Answer (score 0):

In dashboard go to  `Apperance -> menu -> Show advanced menu properties`

Click checkbox of `CSS Classes` then you can add common class for parent    menu and seperate common class for child menu.